# Asynchronous Behavior in JavaScript: setTimeout and IIEF

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, settimeout, iife

```js
var arr = [10, 24, 15, 4];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    (function (index) {
      return function () {
        console.log("index:" + index + " element: " + arr[index]);
      };
    })(i),
    1000
  );
}
```

---

##### Output :-

```
index:0 element: 10
index:1 element: 24
index:2 element: 15
index:3 element: 4
```

---

My understanding is that in JavaScript, asynchronous functions (like the callbacks scheduled by `setTimeout`) are executed only after all synchronous code has run. In this case, I would expect the for loop to complete before any of the `setTimeout` callbacks are invoked. Since it's declared with `var`, it should have a function scope, and by the time the `setTimeout` callbacks are invoked, it should be equal to `arr.length` (which is 4).

However, the output shows that each callback is logging the correct index and element from the array. This is the case even when I change `var` to `let`.

Could someone help me understand why this is the case? How does JavaScript handle the execution of these asynchronous callbacks in relation to the synchronous for loop, and why does the use of var or let not make a difference in this context?

Any insights or resources for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't asynchronous. And since all your timeouts have the same schedule, they just go into a list of callbacks to be executed once that time has somewhat elapsed and the next check for timing functions is called. And at that point, they just happen synchronously again.

Comment: "*However, the output shows that each callback is logging the correct index and element from the array.*" that's because you're capturing the *value* at each iteration in the IIFE. JS is not pass-by-reference.

Comment: Your code is basically showing how old JS used to scope vars,  these days you could just use `let` instead of `var`..

Comment: It's a bit like why this logs 10 and not 0 -> `var x = 10; (function () { var y = x; setTimeout(function () {console.log(y)}, 1000)})(); x = 0;`   But instead your IFFE is just using function params to capture scope instead.

Comment: "*I would expect the for loop to complete before any of the setTimeout callbacks are invoked. Since it's declared with var, it should have a function scope, and by the time the setTimeout callbacks are invoked, it should be equal to arr.length (which is 4).*" - yes, yes, and yes. "*However, the output shows that each callback is logging the correct index and element from the array.*"  - that is because the callback is using `index`, not `i`, for which the previous paragraph applies. `index` is not declared as a `var` on the loop, the IIFE is called during the loop execution not asynchronously.

Comment: @Keith might be even clearer if we drop the IIFE for a simple named function and demonstrate the not-pass-by-reference behaviour: https://jsbin.com/pacavegazu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ yeah that will help too, my main point was the `var y = x;`,  kind of make it more clear it's a copy, just in case the function params part was the bit the OP was struggling with.   Just another way of looking at it..  IOW: The OP could have also done `var index = i;`